# C: with power function converting binary to decimal

Tags: c, rounding, pow

I am trying to convert decimal number to binary number using recursion.
But I am getting wrong output...I tried to debug the program and got stuck with "pow()".
I inserted many printf statements to see the status of the variables...
Here is my program...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>   
#include<math.h>

void main(){
int n,k;
int z;
long b,j;
long binary(int,int);
printf("Enter a Number : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Binary Equivalent is : ");
k=log2(n);
b=binary(n,k);
z=pow(10,k); 
printf("\n\nb=%d ,z=%d",b,z); 
}



long binary(int n,int c)
{
    int a,np;
    static long b=0;
    if(n<=1){
        b=(n%2)*(int)pow(10,c)+b;
        printf("\n nmod2=%d\nb=%ld\nc=%d\nn=%d ",(n%2),b,c,n);
        return b;
    }
    else{
        a=n%2;  
        np=pow(10,c);
        b=a*np+b;
        printf("\n a=%d,np=%d \n nmod2=%d \n b=%ld \n c=%d \n n=%d ",a,np,(n%2),b,c,n);
        binary(n/2,--c);
    }
}


Output is:
Enter a Number : 5
Binary Equivalent is :
 a=1,np=99
nmod2=1
b=99    
c=2    
n=5
 a=0,np=10
nmod2=0
b=99
c=1
n=2
 nmod2=1
b=100
c=0
n=1

b=100 ,z=100
```

why the "pow(10,c)" in binary() when c=2 equals 99 why not 100 as in main()?

Comment: Wow. 1-letter variable names, total absence of comments, recursion... Are you participating in the International Obfuscated C Code Contest (IOCCC)?

Comment: I wrote such code ages ago. This changed when I first tried to read it back, and adopt to new requirements. Painful experience...

Comment: The OICCC would never accept `void main()`

Comment: You shouldn't need to use pow at all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
(int)pow(10,c)
```

The result is around 100, but rounding it down with `(int)` can get you either 99 or 100 depending on the roundoff error of `pow`.

This is a handy function [`lround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) in `math.h` that should help you. It rounds a number towards the closest integer, rounding `0.5` towards zero.

Alternatively, you could define:

```
int my_round(double f) {
    return (int)(f+0.5);
}
```

Adding 0.5 and rounding down looks like rounding to the closest integer.

Comment: Please note that there is a standard function `round()`, which has the syntax `double round(double x)`. It would be wise to pick a different name. Or better, use the appropriate standard function: `long int lround(double x);` found in math.h.

Answer (score 1):

The pow() function is a floating-point function, which tends to screw up such stuff. You shouldn't use it for integers without proper rounding to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems.

1. As others have point out that the result of `pow(10,c)` is the problem.  A *good* `pow()` would return *exactly* 100.0 for `pow(10,2)`.  It is reasonable to expect that behavior from `pow()`, but a cautious programmer would do as others suggest and round-to-nearest a floating point number to an `int`.
2. Round to nearest is best handle with a library function.  Should one want to roll your own:

   `int IRound(double f) { return (f > 0.0) ? (int)(f + 0.5) : (int)(f - 0.5); }`
3. `long binary(int n,int c)` does not return a value when `n > 1`.  Suspect `return binary(n/2,--c)` is wanted.
4. The `static long b=0;` is a *bad* way to deal with recursion.  `long binary(int n,int c)` would nominally correctly run only once.  A second call, `b` would not necessarily start at `0`.
5. Given `pow()` is flaky, `log2()` may need special care too.